# List all locations from a single account in Google my business API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-my-business-api, google-my-business

My requirement is I'm trying to get all the reviews from all the locations of an account. So first I'm trying to list all the locations in an account using:
`https://mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com/v1/{parent=accounts/****}/locations`

I'm using Google Oauth2 Playground to replicate this scenario but getting 404 not found error.

[image]

However I can list all the accounts using: `https://mybusinessaccountmanagement.googleapis.com/v1/accounts` this gives me all the accounts.

But how to get all the locations from a single account?

Comment: Did you activate the second API?

Comment: Can we get a anonymized version of the exact request you are sending? E.g. replace the actual account IDs with 123...789. What query parameters are you setting?

Comment: Yes, both the APIs are enabled.

Comment: ```https://mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com/v1/accounts/117163.......7290...757/locations``` I'm expecting all the location_ids corresponding to the given account.

Comment: Do you have quota >0 for both APIs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query parameter readMask is required, the request should look like:

> [https://mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com/v1/accounts/117163.......7290...757/locations?readMask=name](https://-)